# How can I make long tuple list of URLs separate into JSON objects?

Tags: python, json, tuples

I have a long tuple list of URLs that I would like to convert to JSON format in a specific way that allows each tuple item to be in their own nested object.

Kinda puzzled at how to manage to do that.
I'm trying to convert the tuple into JSON so that it looks as such...

```
        "links": [
            {
                "src": tuple-item-1
            },
            {
                "src": tuple-item-2
            },
            {
                "src": tuple-item-3
            }
            ...
        ]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean by long truple list?

Comment: Can you please update the post with **real** input and output examples?

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74691923/20603322) solved your problem? Do let me know. And don’t forget to upvote and accept my answer.